# How to convert LaTex to PDF using terminal?

Tags: command-line, package-management, dpkg, pdf, latex

I am trying to convert latex file (.tex) file into pdf format. I tried using **pdflatex file_name.tex** command from the terminal but terminal asks to enter file name again and again. The commands in the terminal are as

```
{This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./file_name.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `spie.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: }
```

Comment: VTC as not about Ubuntu because this is a TeX question.

Answer (score 4):

Your LaTeX file needs the file `spie.cls`. Install the package `texlive-publishers` which [provides](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=spie.cls) this file.

Comment: Also, we can add "-interaction=nonstopmode" if it shows warnings.(in my case it did)